# Where can I find a link to download SubStage?

Tags: subsonic

Where can I find a link to download SubSonic SubStage?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be part of the SubSonic download:

http://subsonicproject.googlecode.com/files/SubSonic_2.1_Final_Source.zip

If not, you can pull it from the source here:

http://subsonicproject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Answer (score 0):

I kown the website,but don't install it